# Configuring NuGet dependencies and VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I wish to set up my NuGet dependencies such that:

1. Anyone checking out the project (i.e. other developers) will get the correct dependencies.
2. Anyone using my package will get the correct dependencies.

In VS2013 my NuGet dependencies are specified in packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I noticed that you can also specify dependencies in the .nuspec file (much like a maven pom file) but this doesn't seem to be used by the package manager plugin.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.3"/>
</dependencies>
```

What is the correct way to configure dependencies and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *packages.config* file lists all the packages that are currently installed for a given project. This includes any dependencies. NuGet will automatically update this file any time you add, update, or remove packages from your project, either through the NuGet UI or Package Manager Console (e.g. Install-Package  log4net).

NuGet will automatically install any dependencies for a given package. NuGet will also follow the dependency chain for each of these other packages, until all dependent packages are installed. It will add these packages to the *packages.config* file to show that they have been installed. So you may initially install one package, but 10 packages may end up being installed based on all the dependencies. Again, this will be reflected in the *packages.config* file, which you shouldn't touch.

You do NOT need to edit this file.

The only way you should update *packages.config* is by installing or updating packages via the NuGet UI or Package Manager Console. Do not edit this file by hand.

**EDIT: Add section about package restore**

The *packages.config* file is also used by NuGet to restore packages (Automatic Package Restore) that do not exist on the user's hard drive. This is useful since you do not have to commit the packages folder to source control. So when another developer checks out your project, NuGet will automatically download any packages listed in *packages.config* before building. NOTE: This is not the same as installing packages. It is assumed that you've already used NuGet to install the package, which will update project references, add files, modify .config files, etc. Those changes should already be committed. All package restore does is download the binaries as if they were also committed, without bloating your repository. Package restore is mainly used for other developers building your project from source code. It is not applicable for installing a package you create, which is what the .nuspec file is for.

The *.nuspec* file is used when you are creating your OWN packages for others to use. The `<dependencies/>` section lists the packages YOUR package needs. When a developer installs YOUR package, NuGet will automatically install any dependencies listed in your .nuspec. Just like above, NuGet will follow the dependency chain by looking at each packages .nuspec file to see what dependencies it requires.

So unless you're CREATING a package, you do not have to worry about .nuspec files.

As you can see, NuGet uses the .nuspec file in each package to determine if there are any dependencies. Installing a package will update the *packages.config* files.

**TL;DR: *packages.config* and *.nuspec* files are different things although somewhat related.**

Comment: Added sentence that says you should only edit packages.config by using the NuGet UI or Package Manager Console... don't edit by hand.

Comment: Sorry, also added a section about package restore, since it somewhat applies to your question. Again, that's more for other developers building your project from source. Not installing a package you create.